# Flexbox layout breaks when content is not equal

Tags: css, flexbox

I've built a working three-column flexbox layout that contains *cards*, to which I've now introduced [jQuery Flip](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/).

The following is my structure:

```
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-flip">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="card-img four-three-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/gsnJi.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <h2>Event title</h2>
          <h3>Event date</h3>
          <h3>Event venue</h3>
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
          <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="button purple-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="card-img four-three-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/gsnJi.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <h2>Event title</h2>
          <h3>Event date</h3>
          <h3>Event venue</h3>
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
          <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="button purple-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.events-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.events-row .card {
  flex-basis: 31.3%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}
.events-row .card .card-img {
  position: relative;
}
.events-row .card .card-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.events-row .card .card-info {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

The problem is that if the contents of `.back` accumulate to a height smaller than `.front`'s, the `.card` element's height shrinks to match `.back`. If the contents of `.back` and `.front` are equal, or if there's no `.back` at all (see working layout demo), the layout doesn't break.

Basically, the `.card` height is based on the contents of `.back`, but I'd like it to be based on the contents of `.front`.

I've played around with the flexbox CSS, but I can't figure out what's causing this. Any help would be very appreciated!

Demos (inspect `.card` to see different effects):

- Broken layout: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/xgrLJq
- Working layout:
  http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/xgrLoL